# How to reject null values in Swagger

Tags: java, spring-boot, swagger, openapi

We are implementing an application which exposes an API that has the interface described by an `api.swagger.yaml` file. We build our application with Gradle and part of the build process we parse the `api.swagger.yaml` file and generate the classes modelling the request response classes. For this we use the `org.openapitools:openapi-generator-gradle-plugin:6.6.0` Gradle plugin. The Gradle task that does this is configured like below:

```
//https://github.com/OpenAPITools/openapi-generator/tree/master/modules/openapi-generator-gradle-plugin
task buildApiModel(type: org.openapitools.generator.gradle.plugin.tasks.GenerateTask) {
    generatorName = "java"
    library = "webclient"
    inputSpec = "$rootDir/src/main/resources/swagger/v3/api.swagger.yaml".toString()
    outputDir = "$buildDir/myapp-generated-api/".toString()
    modelPackage = "com.my.comp.myapp.api.dto"
    generateModelTests = false
    generateApiTests = false
    skipValidateSpec = true
    configOptions = [
            java11                        : "true",
            dateLibrary                   : "java11",
            interfaceOnly                 : "true",
            additionalModelTypeAnnotations: "@lombok.experimental.SuperBuilder @lombok.AllArgsConstructor @JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL)"
    ]
```

In our Swagger we define the request which is a complex structure with some embedded structures, say one of them is called `trafficMap` which in turn has a property called `semaphore` which in turn has a **required** property called `colour` which colour property can only have three values: `green`, `yellow` and `red`. It is a requirement that colour property is always passed and cannot be null. In our Swagger file this will look like this:

```yaml
trafficMap:
  title: ...
  description: ...
  type: object
  properties:
    semaphore:
      description: ...
      type: object
      properties:
        colour:
          description: ...
          type: string
          enum:
            - GREEN
            - YELLOW
            - RED
      required:
        - colour
```

With the above, the generated Semaphore class will have these annotations regarding the colour property:

```java
public class Semaphore {
    public enum ColourEnum {
        GREEN("GREN"),
        YELLOW("YELLOW"),
        RED("RED");

        private String value;
        
        ColourEnum(String value) {
            this.value = value;
        }
        
        @JsonValue
        public String getValue() {
            return value;
        }
        
        @JsonCreator
        public static ColourEnum fromValue(String value) {
            for (ColourEnum b : ColourEnum.values()) {
                if (b.value.equals(value)) {
                   return b;
                }
            }
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Unexpected value '" + value + "'");
        }
              
     public Semaphore() {
     }
     
     public Semaphore colour(ColourEnum colour) {
        this.colour = colour;
        return this;
     }
     
     @javax.annotation.Nonnull
     @JsonProperty(JSON_PROPERTY_COLOUR)
     @JsonInclude(value = JsonInclude.Include.ALWAYS)
     public ColourEnum getColour() {
         return colour;
     }

     @JsonProperty(JSON_PROPERTY_COLOUR)
     @JsonInclude(value = JsonInclude.Include.ALWAYS)
     public void setColour(ColourEnum colour) {
         this.colour = colour;
     }
     // ... The rest of the generated Semaphore class
}
```

When sending the request and setting the colour property to `BLUE` the request gets rejected as it should with a message `Invalid semaphore.colour` in the response body.

However, if we pass a null value for colour or we miss the colour entirely from the request, we don't get a rejection and the request hits the controller instead. We would like the generated code to do this validation for us as opposed to implementing extra validation on the service side.

We thought the reason for this behaviour was the this annotation in the generated code: `@JsonInclude(value = JsonInclude.Include.ALWAYS)` which from JsonInclude documentation could cause accepting any value including null.

```java
public enum Include
{
    /**
     * Value that indicates that property is to be always included,
     * independent of value of the property.
     */
    ALWAYS,

    /**
     * Value that indicates that only properties with non-null
     * values are to be included.
     */
    NON_NULL,
```

So the natural thing that came to our mind was to try to replace the `JsonInclude.Include.ALWAYS` with `JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL`. To do this we added these two `x` attributes in the `api.swagger.yaml` for the `colour` property

```yaml
colour:
  description: ...
  type: string
  x-setter-annotation: "@JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL)"
  x-field-extra-annotation: "@JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL)"
  enum:
  ....
```

The only difference in the generated code that we noticed was that `Colour` field of the `Semaphore` class was now annotated with `NON_NULL` but the getter and setter methods still had the `ALWAYS` JsonInclude and the app still does not reject the null values for colour.

```java
@JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL)
private ColourEnum colour;
```

```java
@RestController
@RequestMapping(value = "/v3/some")
@Validated
public void StuffController {
    @PostMapping(value = "/stuff", consumes = APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE, produces = APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
    public ResponseEntity<CreateStuffResponse> createStuff(
        @RequestBody @Valid Payee request, @RequestHeader HttpHeaders httpHeaders) throws Exception {
    ...
    }
}
```

How can we configure our swagger to generate code that would reject the request if a null value is passed for colour?

Comment: The model parameter in the controller method needs to be annotated with `@Valid` so that the `@javax.annotation.Nonnull` is validated, or maybe you're using Spring Boot 3, which only supports `@jakarta.annotation.Nonnull` instead.

Comment: Annotated request body with `@javax.validation.Valid` as suggested. This was in addition to having the controller class annotated with `@org.springframework.validation.annotation.Validated` already. It made no difference; still let the null values for colour pass through. We are using Spring Boot 2.7.12

Comment: Then please edit your question and include the controller.